# Ajuda com socket cliente/servidor com interações matematicas de soma em python

Tags: python

Estou estudando sobre socket e queria fazer um socket que quando o cliente digita 5 e outro 5 o servidor responde 10 e retorna para o cliente a resposta.
Como eu mudo meu código para ter essa interação?

** arquivo socket_servidor.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
from time import time, ctime

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while 1:
print ("waiting for connection...")
tcpClisock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
print ("...connected from:"), addr

while 1:
data = tcpClisock.recv(BUFSIZ)
print ("[+] %s") % (data)
if data=="exit": 
exit
tcpClisock.send("[SERVER]vc digitou "+data) 

tcpClisock.close()
exit
tcpSerSock.close()
```

** arquivo socket_cliente.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from socket import * 


HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 21567 
BUFSIZ = 1024 
ADDR = (HOST, PORT) 

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR) 

while 1: 
data = raw_input("CLIENT > ")
print ("[CLIENT] vc digitou %s") % (data) 
if not data: 
break
tcpCliSock.send(data) 
data = tcpCliSock.recv(1024) 

if not data: 
break 
print (data) 

tcpCliSock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode declarar uma variável global no servidor (`socket_servidor.py`) para servir de contador:

```
soma = 0
...
if data == "exit":
    exit
else
    soma += data
    print(soma)
```